# Почему после выделения памяти и lstrcatA() вылетает программа

Tags: c++, указатели

Я использую код

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void create(char* ptr, int size)
{
    ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * size);
}

int main()
{
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    create(ptr, 2000);
    char str[] = "TEXT_TEXT_TEXT_123";
    lstrcatA(ptr, str);
}
```

И у меня вылетает программа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при выделении памяти не через функцию всё в порядке

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void create(char* ptr, int size)
{
    ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * size);
}

int main()
{
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2000);
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * 2000);
    char str[] = "TEXT_TEXT_TEXT_123";
    lstrcatA(ptr, str);
}
```

то есть когда выделаю память не через функцию то всё в порядке. Скажите пожалуйста в чем тут разница если я выделаю память через функцию по одинаковой схеме.

Comment: Вы не меняете значение переменной `ptr` в `main` после инициализации нулевым указателем.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что вы внутри функции инициализируете указатель, но не возвращаете его в управляющую программу.

Варианты решения:

1. Вернуть его как результат функции

   ```c
   char * create(int size)
   {
       char * ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
       memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * size);
       return ptr;
   }

   char* ptr = create(2000);
   ```
2. Передать в функцию двойной указатель

   ```c
   void create(char ** ptr, int size)
   {
       *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
       memset(*ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * size);
   }

   char* ptr = nullptr;
   create(&ptr, 2000);
   ```
3. Передать в функцию ссылку на указатель

   ```c
   void create(char * &ptr, int size)
   {
       ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
       memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * size);
   }

   char* ptr = nullptr;
   create(ptr, 2000);
   ```